# Symfony 2 - having troubles with asset function

Tags: symfony, assets

I'm having troubles with calling stylesheets and javascript via asset() function..

my app is running on dev enviorment so the url is - dproc.local/app_dev.php/

The base.css is in /src/Dproc/Resources/views/Dproc/css/base.css

```
   <link href="{{ asset('/css/base.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Doesnt work.

How should my link have to be? I didnt understood how asset() function works..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the command

```
asset install --web
```

so that the asset files are copied to web folder.